# Accepting Sockets Only From Specific IPs

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming, udp, sfml

My game server is now accepting sockets from every one. But how can I block specific IPs from attack? You know, if they would like to crash my server or something. I'm using SFML library, C++.

Comment: Are you using the SFML SocketTCP and SocketUDP classes?

Answer (score 2):

With TCP, when your program (or the library you are using) calls `accept(2)`, the second argument is an output which tells you the client's address.

With UDP there are no connections, but there is `recvfrom(2)`, which just like `accept(2)`, gives you the peer's address.  So you can ignore the peers you don't like.

Or you can run your server behind some sort of firewall appliance and add rules there, or use iptables or similar as a software firewall on the host machine.

In SFML you have `SocketTCP::Accept` and `SocketUDP::Receive`, both of which will give you the peer's address if you pass an empty address as an argument.

Comment: OK, so just after the request check the IP?

Comment: Yup, just after `accept()`, check the returned IP and close the connection if the IP is black listed (or not whitelisted).

Comment: What about UDP? I mean, a user can bomb my server with tons of data and than my bandwidth would get crazy.

Comment: For UDP all you can do is drop (ignore) the packets.  You can set up a firewall on your router, but that just moves the place they are flooding you with packets further out.  (Of course, they could flood your router with packets right now, even before you write this game server.)

Comment: I expanded my answer to deal with UDP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any specific method for blocking some ips, but you can surely reject the request (probably connection request in your case) after determining the originating ip. Maintain a list of blocked ip (or BlackListed ip) (make it configurable as well for easier additions/deletions) and reject the request if it is coming from one of the Black Listed ips.

Comment: OK, so just after the request check the IP?

Comment: yes (using some think like: getperrname), that would surely work in your case.

Comment: What about UDP? I mean, a user can bomb my server with tons of data and than my bandwidth would get crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, WinSock 2.x has an optional callback parameter for `WSAAccept()` that can be used to conditionally accept/reject connection requests.  Client IP/Port is one of the available parameters.